# Would an electroscope work if it were not in a glass container?

Tags: experimental-physics, charge

I'm reading about the [gold-leaf electroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroscope#Gold-leaf_electroscope) and all the sources I've read show that the gold leaves are placed in a glass container. Is there something special about the glass, or would any container work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for enclosing the gold leaf in a container is simply that gold leaf is exceedingly delicate. The container protects the gold leaf from air currents that would otherwise move the gold leaves or even tear them.

The exact nature of the container isn't important, and any container would work, though obviously we need it to be transparent so we can see the leaves.

Comment: You also don't want your electroscope to discharge because of ions in the air, you want it to discharge because of cosmic rays.